# How to fix 'undefined name' in flutter stream input validation?

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, stream

I want to validate an input through the stream transformer function and I get an error when I pass in the value of the password as a 'pass/password' argument before the sink argument.

I tried different names but it's not working. It works fine with my email validator but I don't know why it's an error with the password validator although they are almost exactly the same.

```
final passValidate = StreamTransformer<String,String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (pass,sink)
    if (pass.length >4){
      sink.add(pass);
    }
    else
    {
      sink.addError('wrong pass');
    }
  );
```

I expected the argument to be run normally but I get an error message of "Undefined name 'pass'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name"